# Definition of '$=$' in my book.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, logic, definition

Is the following definition of '$=$' between numbers (natural, whole, rational, real, complex) correct?

$a=b$ iff $a$ and $b$ denote the same number.

> **EDIT:**

This is the first page of my book "[Classical Analysis](http://93.174.95.29/_ads/31ED57ED5DC856CD93122037933C49F2)"

> [image]

It is said that '$=$' is an [equivalence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312408/confusion-in-the-equivalence-relation-statement).

So what does the book mean by '$=$'?

Comment: What do you mean by "denote the same number"? This isn't very clear.

Comment: In this case, $=$ means **equivalent** and not *equal*. Usually this is written $a\sim b$ and not $a=b$. Therefore the confusion you had, perhaps. Your text has still the same question, so I cannot remove the duplicate. Actually, you already asked about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312408/confusion-in-the-equivalence-relation-statement).

Comment: The page begins by defining the axioms of an equivalence relation, and to keep the notation succinct it works with algebraic expressions in which an arbitrary equivalence relation has a symbol, and the symbol chosen is $=$. Equality, the usual meaning of $=$, is just one equivalence relation; a different equivalence relation may be denoted $=$ if the context makes clear either (i) which one is intended or (ii) that arbitrary equivalence relations are being discussed, as here.

Comment: See the definition of group [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition). The wiki talks about "equality", not "equivalence". **Does the equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ in my book refer to "equality" also?**

Comment: I think this is extremely awful, for at least three reasons. First, using "$=$" for an arbitrary equivalence relation, as in the first paragraph, is a very bad idea since  that symbol has a different standard meaning, namely equality. (Do those equations refer to equality? Who can tell? The second big problem is he says something about an equivalence relation and an operation without introducing proper notation for them! To make the rest of the definition intelligible "an operation such that" should be ...

Comment: "an operation $\circ$ such that" - as it stands we have to _guess_  that $\circ$  is "the operation". Similarly for "an equivalence relation" - if he'd specified the notation properly we wouldn't have to guess what $=$ means.) Third, there is no equivalence relation in the _**standard**_ definitiion of "group"! The word "group" in this book means something different from what it  means **everywhere** else - bad bad bad bad bad idea. If this is representative of the rest of the text you really need a different book.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Therefore it seems to me the first chapter of the book (which deals with the construction of real numbers) is horribly awful. Can you suggest some other books which also covers the topics in the first chapter of [this book](http://93.174.95.29/_ads/31ED57ED5DC856CD93122037933C49F2)?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498660/589

Comment: Other books: What ihf said.

Comment: This book is from 1955.  I wonder how common this point of view was back then.  A recent example is J. Conway, *On Numbers and Games*, where we define equality of numbers (and of games)  using an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 5):

It's been commented that "usually" an equivalence relation is denoted by $\sim$ instead of $=$. It seems to me that in fact $=$ is *never* used for an equivalence relation (other than equality). Using $=$ for an arbitrary equivalence relation is a hugely bad idea.

(i) It causes confusion.

(ii) It means we have no way to  denote actual equality! That's a problem, for example:

If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation a standard definition of the "equivalence class" containing $x$ is $$[x]_\sim=\{y:y\sim x\}.$$ If we're using "$=$" to denote an equivalence relation then how can we write that definition? It  becomes
$$[x]_==\{y:y= x\},$$which is impossibly bad notation: The symbol $=$ appears three times, twice referring to the equivalence relation under consideration and once to  actual equality. Using the same symbol for two different things - totally wrong. I mean it looks like the author hasn't mastered basic undergraduate mathematical concepts.

(If as you say he's about to construct the real numbers then he *will* be talking about equivalence classes - I wonder how he gives the definition.)

---

**The Point to Equivalence Relations and Equivalence Classes**

To be fair, we should note that often the reason we introduce ann equivalence relation is we want to extend the meaning of "=". Fine, but we'd better not use the same symbol!

For example, say we have the integers $\Bbb Z$ and we want to define the rational numbers. We think about it: All that matters about $n/m$ is the values of $n$ and $m$, so could just talk about ordered pairs, since we already know what they are:

> > **Def 1.** A *rational number* is an ordered pair $(n,m)$ of integers with $m\ne0$.

That amounts to defining $1/2$ by $1/2=(1,2)$. Fine, except it doesn't work. We certainly want a definition such that $1/2=2/4$, but $(1,2)\ne(2,4)$.

"*Intuitively*" we change the defiinition:

> > **Def 2.** A rational number is an ordered pair $(n,m)$ of integers with $m\ne0$, except that $(n,m)=(p,q)$ if $nq=mp$.

That works better; now we have $1/2=(1,2)=(2,4)=2/4$, great. **But** the problem with that is we've redefined what "$=$" means, leading to problems like (i)  and  (ii) above.

So we introduce an equivalence relation. Say $$X=\{(n,m):n,m\in\Bbb Z, m\ne0\}.$$Define a relation $\sim$ on $X$ by $$(n,m)\sim(p,q)\text{ if }nq=mp.$$You verify that $\sim$ is ann equivalence  relation, and now

> > **Def 3.** A *rational number* is $[(n,m)]_\sim$ for $(n,m)\in X$.

(Or briefly, $\Bbb Q=X/\sim$.)

That works, in fact it's the standard definition. The point to Def 3 is we really wanted to give Def 2, but Def 2 makes no sense; Def 3 is  a corrected version of Def 2.

I mention this because you will see many definitions analogous to Def 3; when you're trying to figure out what the definition "really means" the answer is often that it's a corrected version of something analogous  to Def 2.

Comment: that is we have redefined what '$=$' means...... Can you tell what did '$=$' originally mean?

Comment: @Joe The symbol $=$ denotes _equality_: $a=b$ means thar $a$ and $b$ are the same thing,

Comment: By same thing, do you mean the same member of the set?

Comment: @Joe Note $a=b$ means that $a$ and $b$ _are_ the same thing, not that they "denote" the same thing. $a/2=2/4$, but $1/2$ does not _denote_ anything, because ii is not an expression! The two expressions "$1/2$" and "$2/4$" denote the same thing, but $1/2\ne"1/2"$; the first is a number while the second  is a sequence of symbols.

Comment: By "same thing" I mean they are exactly the same thing! This doesn't necessarilly have anything to do  with sets. Saying $1/2=2/4$ means that $1/2$ annd $2/4$ are _identical_.

Comment: No, when I say "thing" I don't mean "member of a set". It's impossible to define _every_ word without being circular. You sound like a native English speaker - when I say "thing" I mean _anything_. (circular...) $1/2$ is a thing. Chicago is a thing. You are a thing. Justice, truth and beauty are things...

Comment: Very nice explanation in second part which shows the importance of equivalence relations in definitions. +1